# Method not found: 'Void Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiDictionary.Connect()'

Tags: c#, reporting-services, windows, stimulsoft

I am developing Windows application in C#.net And I want to report from a table using stimulSoft. So I used stimulsoft Report Viewer and this code:

```
StiReport myreport = new StiReport();
myreport.Dictionary.Databases.Add(new Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiSqlDatabase("DBConn", "Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = HoghooghDastmozd; Integrated Security = True"));
myreport.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Report.mrt");
myreport.Dictionary.Variables["IDP"].Value = textBox1.Text;
stiViewerControl1.Report = myreport;
```

But I am getting this error:

> Method not found: 'Void
>   Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiDictionary.Connect()'

Comment: did you import the Stimulsoft library?

Comment: Yes.I imported dll files

Comment: And you also imported them inside the class where you want to use these methods? For example: using Stimulsoft; ?

Comment: But where are you using the connect method in your code?

Comment: I have not used it

Comment: So why are you getting this error? Can you give some more details?

Comment: I don't know.If I knew I wouldn't ask

Comment: Maybe you could check this out: https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/